# Identify json type in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13

Is there a function - or a way to easily determine the json data type in postgresql?

For example:

```
select key, value, pg_typeof(value) FROM jsonb_each('{"foo":1,"bar":"2","ack":[1,2,3]}'::jsonb)
```

Returns:

```
key value   pg_typeof
ack [1, 2, 3]   jsonb
bar "2" jsonb
foo 1   jsonb
```

How would I determine that the value for ack is an array, bar is a string, and foo is a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  here [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), `jsonb_typeof`:

```
 select key, value, jsonb_typeof(value) FROM jsonb_each('{"foo":1,"bar":"2","ack":[1,2,3]}'::jsonb);
 key |   value   | jsonb_typeof 
-----+-----------+--------------
 ack | [1, 2, 3] | array
 bar | "2"       | string
 foo | 1         | number
```

Comment: Now I feel foolish. Thanks for the help!